# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ for the following linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The following linear system is as follows:

$$ax+y+0=a$$
$$x+y+z=1$$
$$0+y+az=b$$

Find $a$ and $b$ such that the linear system has:
1. No solution
2. Exactly one solution
3. Infinitely many solutions

The row-echelon form of the augmented matrix of the linear system is this after working it out using Gauss Elimination:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&1&1&1\\
      0&1&a&b\\0&0&a^2-2a&ab-b
    \end{array}
\right] $$

For this to have no solution, $$a^2-2a=0$$
Therefore: $$a=2, a=0$$

However, I will need to substitute it into $ab-b$ and ensure that $ab-b$ is not 0.
$$a=0, ab-b=-b$$
$$a=2, ab-b=b$$

Therefore: $$a=0, b\in\mathbb R-(0)$$
$$a=2, b\in\mathbb R-(0)$$

However, I do need some help with regards to having exactly one solution and infinitely many solutions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

from the first equation we get
$$y=a-ax$$ and from the second we get
$$z=1-x-a+ax$$ thus we get
$$a-a x+(1-x-a+ax)=b$$
simplifying we have
$$x(-a-a +a^2)=b+a^2-2a$$
can you finish?

Comment: I used your equations to obtain $x$, $y$ and $z$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

$$x=1-b$$
$$y=ab$$
$$z=b(1-a)$$

Any hints on how do I continue?

Comment: and where is $\alpha$?

Comment: Oh that $a$ is the same $a$, for the first equation

Comment: now i got $$x(-2a+a^2)=b+a^2-2a$$

Comment: I simplified the 3rd equation to obtain $x=1-b$

Comment: this is wrong you can not do this

Comment: note that $$x=\frac{a^2-2a+b}{a^2-2a}$$ if $$a^2-2a\ne 0$$

Comment: As in your third equation, if I simplify that I will obtain $x=1-b$.
Sorry I am not sure about this but can I ask why is this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have that:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{a}\cdot\text{x}+\text{y}+0=\text{a}\\
\\
\text{x}+\text{y}+\text{z}=1\\
\\
0+\text{y}+\text{a}\cdot\text{z}=\text{b}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

Now, simplifying and solving $\text{a}$ out of the first equation:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{a}=\frac{\text{y}}{1-\text{x}}\\
\\
\text{y}=1-\text{x}-\text{z}\\
\\
\text{y}+\text{a}\cdot\text{z}=\text{b}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

So, for the third equation we get:

$$1-\text{x}-\text{z}+\frac{1-\text{x}-\text{z}}{1-\text{x}}\cdot\text{z}=1-x+\frac{\text{z}^2}{x-1}=\text{b}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{z}=\pm\sqrt{\text{x}-1}\cdot\sqrt{\text{b}+\text{x}-1}\tag3$$

Comment: Do I need to solve for $x$ in terms of $a$ and $b$ in order to continue?

Comment: @Derp Maybe that is a good start